# Conditional Probability of Binomial Distribution

Tags: conditional-probability

If $Y_{1}\sim \text{Bin}(n_{1},\pi)$ and $Y_{2}\sim\text{Bin}(n_{2},\pi))$ are independent. Then find the conditional distribution of $Y_{1}$ given $Y_{1}+Y_{2} = m$. How do I calculate $\textbf{P}(Y_{1} = k|Y_{1}+Y_{2} = m)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The sum of two independent binomial random variables is also binomial. Therefore we have that $Y_{1} + Y_{2} \sim \text{Bin}(n_{1} + n_{2},\pi)$. Can you take it from here?